# How to verify the compressed signature in Bitcoin? It is 138 long in hex

Tags: bitcore, bitcoinjs, node.js, ruby

I am using the `bicoinjs-message` npm module for signature verification.

I learned that there are few signatures which are of length 138 in hexadecimal.
When I tried to verify such a signature it is throwing an error:

> Error: Invalid signature length

How to verify the compressed signature?
I think there is a lib in ruby, [bitcoin-ruby 0.0.20](https://rubygems.org/gems/bitcoin-ruby/versions/0.0.20), which verifies it, but I don't know ruby.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the bitcoin core software, you should be able to use the CLI to verify signatures using the `verifymessage` command. Some wallet software also has this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

There are no compressed signatures. Bitcoin uses two different formats (encodings) for signatures:

- *transaction* signatures use the ASN.1 DER encoding, which is variable length depending on the curve and was common when Satoshi published, and adds a 'sighash' byte. For secp256k1 in general, DER(ECDSA-Sig) is *usually* 72-70 bytes and sometimes but rarely less, but modern bitcoin requires 'low-S' signatures which reduces the maximum to 71. A 69-byte (138-hexit) signature *excluding* sighash would occur about 3/512 (about one-half a percent) of the time; that length *including* sighash would be much rarer.
- *message* signatures use the P1363 encoding, also called 'plain', 'PKCS11', or 'CVC', which for secp256k1 is always exactly 64 bytes, and adds a recovery byte for a total of 65 (always). It also addes a prefix to the signed data, which changes the value(s) but not the format of the signature.

See e.g.:
[Why the signature is always 65 (1+32+32) bytes long?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/12554/why-the-signature-is-always-65-13232-bytes-long)
[ECDSA r, s encoding as a signature](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/2376/ecdsa-r-s-encoding-as-a-signature)
[Difference between Sign Message and Sign Transaction](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/90799/difference-between-sign-message-and-sign-transaction)

Though I haven't looked at it, I expect a library named `bitcoinjs-message` likely handles signatures for messages not transactions, and any signature that is 69 bytes cannot be a message signature.

Comment: Actually, there is a bitcoin-ruby library in ruby. This lib generates the 138 length message signature.

Comment: A bitcoin message signature cannot ever be '138 length'. Not ever in the entire lifetime of the universe. Something named 'bitcoin-ruby' probably handles transactions, which are the original, core, and main function and purpose of bitcoin -- messages are rare and nearly useless.